# move base for omni?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i am trying to control the omni or mechanum wheels with the move base for autonomous navigation. But as i saw that move base only suppports the diff drive wheels.
Is it possible to use move base anyhow to use for this type of robots also? Or has anyone modified the move base for such robots?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383817/move-base-for-omni-?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2021-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never controlled it with an Omni, but it's probably possible.

You should be able to set the local planner of `move_base` to an omni-controllable planner. Set it in `base_local_planner`  of `move_base`.

A candidate local planner to set is `dwa_local_planner`, which is included in the `navigation` stack. It has a setting for y-axis control. `acc_lim_y`, `max_vel_y`, `min_vel_y`, `vy_samples`.

Also, if you are using `amcl` for self-position estimation, changing `odom_model_type` to `omni` may improve the accuracy of self-position estimation.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1